# Horizontal ImageSlider in Horizontal Recyclerview does not work

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, horizontal-scrolling, horizontalscrollview

I have a horizontal recyclerview that takes up the entire screen. Within that recyclerview is a textview and an imageslider than holds three images.

I used this for the imageslider:
https://github.com/denzcoskun/ImageSlideshow

Recyclerview XML

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/bonus_detail_recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:listitem="@layout/bonus_detail_item"/>
```

Bonus Detail XML

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/bonus_detail_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.07"
        android:background="@color/myOrange"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:autoSizeMaxTextSize="100sp"
        android:autoSizeMinTextSize="10sp"
        android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/bonus_image_slider"/>

<com.denzcoskun.imageslider.ImageSlider
        android:id="@+id/bonus_image_slider"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:iss_auto_cycle="false"
        app:iss_period="1000"
        app:iss_delay="0"
        app:iss_placeholder="@drawable/placeholder"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

The problem is that when I try to swipe on the imageslider the entire recyclerview scrolls. I have searched here trying to find a solution, but the option suggested on many other posts does not work for me.

```
    holder.imageSlider.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
            return false;
        }
    });
```

I am not restricted to using the imageSlider, but I do have to maintain the horizontal recyclerview and a horizontal swipe between images. I also tried adding the images in a horizontalscrollview, but I have been unable to set the images to be the full screen width.

Comment: So, the Bonus Detail XML is your `RecyclerView` list item?

Comment: @Zain yes that is correct.

Comment: The problem that both need to consume the scroll event at the same time, and the `RecyclerView` doesn't support nested scrolling in this case. Do you have many items in the recyclerView?

Answer (score 0):

You have to request disallow intercepting touch events on your **`RecyclerView`** not the direct parent of your `ImageSlider` which is `ConstraintLayout`:

```
holder.imageSlider.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            v.getParent()       // ConstraintLayout
                .getParent()    // RecyclerView
                .requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work. Touching the imageSlider still swipes the entire recyclerview.